# What's the best way to add more fields to the Django User model

Tags: django, django-models

I'm a little new to Django. I have created a custom User model because I wanted to use the email for authentication and followed the example in the docs which works well and have the following code:

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, password,
                 is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        now = timezone.now()
        if not email:
           raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email,
                      is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True,
                      is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now,
                      date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, False, False,
                             **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, True, True,
                             **extra_fields)


class User (AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    '''
    Custom User Model
    '''
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name = "email address", max_length = 255, unique = True)
    date_joined  = models.DateTimeField('date joined', default=timezone.now)
    first_name   = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=False)
    last_name    = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=False)
    is_active    = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff     = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%s/" % urlquote(self.email)

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        """
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        "Returns the short name for the user."
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        """
        Sends an email to this User.
        """
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])
```

My only issue now is I want to add additional information to my custom User model such as availability date, profile picture, fee etc (I'm making a mini linkedin site). I feel that adding a ton of extra fields to the User model is a bit messy and with time the amount of fields will grow. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please fix your code's indentation. We can't read it properly as it currently is.

Comment: @Chris fixed the code indentation. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason not to add more fields to this model as you're describing. That's exactly what this custom user model and model migrations are for.

If you're looking to create different user profiles for different users, you could use [multi table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance), like so:

```
class User (AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    '''
    Custom User Model
    '''
    ...fields that are common to CreativeUser and ClientUser

class CreativeUser(User):
    # Fields unique to CreativeUser

class ClientUser(User):
    # Fields unique to ClientUser
```

Now, you can query all users using `User.objects.all()`, you can query `CreativeUser.objects.all()`, or `ClientUser.objects.all()`. Note that `User.objects.all()` will not include any fields that are unique to either of the other two tables.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I guess what worries me is that there will be two types of users: CreativeUser and ClientUser which will share common User traits. Both types of user will hold different things and will go through seperate registration forms, to capture unique information to both types. I wasn't sure if it's best to create a UserProfile model for each type of user with a OneToOneField mapping or just subclass User.

Comment: this worked!!! I used CreativeUser as my form model for the RegistrationForm and the extra fields that I wanted showed up and are saved with the user. Thank you so much? Kudus!!

Answer (score 0):

As for your request i would suggest you to use extension:
[django-custom-user](https://github.com/jcugat/django-custom-user)